# FreeFile Multiple CSVs Error 67 Too many files

Tags: excel, vba, csv

**Background**

I need to open multiple csvs in multiple folders, and for this matter I use FreeFile as input: let's say there are over 1000 csvs (powerquery will not have use here, since I only need the last row of data of each csv and then analyze that). I have seen that expanding to [512](https://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1209377) may temporarily fix it in a way, but I do not think that is the core cause, hence, not providing a long term solution.

**Problem**

Seems like even if I close the file, the memory is not properly cleared, hence I get an [error 67](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/too-many-files-error-67) after some looping on files has been done.

**Code**

I created a function to retrieve the Last Line within my main sub code, I even attempted to loop until freefile is 1 again (I added some sleep as well), but no luck, at some point, grows at 2.

```
Function Return_VarInCSVLine(ByRef NumLineToReturnTo As Long, ByRef TxtFilePathCSV As String, Optional ByRef IsLastLine As Boolean) As Variant
If NumLineToReturnTo = 0 Then NumLineToReturnTo = 1
'NumLineToReturnTo has to be at least 1 even if LastLine is set to true so no error is arised from IIF
Dim NumFileInMemory As Long
Dim ArrVarTxtLines() As Variant
Dim CounterArrTxtLines As Long
Dim TxtInLine As String
    NumFileInMemory = FreeFile: CounterArrTxtLines = 1
    Open TxtFilePathCSV For Input As #NumFileInMemory: DoEvents
    Do While Not EOF(NumFileInMemory)
    Line Input #NumFileInMemory, TxtInLine
    ReDim Preserve ArrVarTxtLines(1 To CounterArrTxtLines)
    ArrVarTxtLines(CounterArrTxtLines) = TxtInLine
    CounterArrTxtLines = CounterArrTxtLines + 1
    Loop
LoopUntilClosed:
    Close #NumFileInMemory: Sleep (10): DoEvents
    NumFileInMemory = FreeFile
    If NumFileInMemory > 1 Then GoTo LoopUntilClosed
    Return_VarInCSVLine = IIf(IsLastLine = True, ArrVarTxtLines(UBound(ArrVarTxtLines)), ArrVarTxtLines(NumLineToReturnTo))
End Function
```

**Question**

How can I avoid this error in this scenario? Or what are my alternatives? I used to do workbooks.Open but that is slower than just using FreeFile and then Open for input

Comment: If you only need the last line then your code could be much simpler - have you tried cutting it down?

Comment: I tried without saving every line and just after the loop is done (thus no array), get the TxtLine, but if I ever want to use it for another line that's not the last, wouldn't work, I wanted to have something more future proof, because the function is working, but overflows after a while

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to use the FileSystemObject on a Windows PC

```
Function fsoReadLine(fileName As String, lineNo As Long, Optional lastLine As Boolean) As String
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim textFile As Object
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set textFile = fso.OpenTextFile(fileName, 1)
        
    Dim vDat As Variant
    ' Read the whole file and split it by lines
    vDat = Split(textFile.ReadAll, vbCrLf)
    
    Dim totalLines As Long
    totalLines = UBound(vDat) + 1  ' zero based array!
    
    If lastLine Then
        fsoReadLine = vDat(totalLines - 1)
    Else
        If lineNo <= totalLines Then
            fsoReadLine = vDat(lineNo - 1)
        End If
    End If
    textFile.Close
    
End Function
```

And if you only need the last line you could shorten the code to

```
Function fsoLastLine(fileName As String) As String
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim textFile As Object
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set textFile = fso.OpenTextFile(fileName, 1)
        
    Dim vDat As Variant
    ' Read the whole file and split it by lines
    vDat = Split(textFile.ReadAll, vbCrLf)
    
    fsoLastLine = vDat(UBound(vDat))
    textFile.Close
    
End Function
```

Comment: Sometimes such a file may end in `vbCrLf`, that's why I think it is good to check if so returned last line is not empty and in such a case return the previous one...

Comment: And sometimes it may end with several blank lines as well. Then you would need to check for the last non-blank line. I think this is a task for the OP if it is needed. But the function will return the last line and that 's what the function is about.

Comment: I can admit that. In fact, his complicated code did not check the emptiness of the last line...

Comment: Thanks @Storax, I am going to test and let know the results.@all  Do not worry for data integrity, I have checkpoints before that (no blanks at the end, not several lines with blanks, no missmatch in data types, etc), so I only needed this sub process to retrieve the end results, but you have a point, just at the moment, is not needed, likely if I re use the function on unorganized data will be, but that's why at least I want to fix it on the best case scenario.

Comment: Thanks, it worked! Would it be too much to ask to explain how is that FileSystem is better at handling the CSV than freefile (as in a massive process like this one where I need to analyze 1000 CSVs)?

Comment: Sorry, but I only get the error message _67 too many files open_ when I forget to close the file. So, I guess, somwehere in your code you forgot the Close statement or the code does not reach the close statement.  I did not analyze that.  I use FileSystemObject because it is availabe on every Windows PC, has not changed for ages (so, no version conflicts) and offers more than the "normal" VBA file interface.

Comment: Yeah, I suspected that too, but close is needed to happen before the function exits, you can see it on the `LoopUntilClosed:    Close #NumFileInMemory: `, anyways, I'll assume to change between one or the other for these purposes